# When to use "weil" and when to use "obwohl"?

Tags: grammatical-case, german-to-english, standard-german, written-language

> Zum Wassertrinken müssen die Giraffen ihre Beine weit auseinander stellen, **weil/obwohl** sie so einen langen Hals haben.

Which one is correct between the sentence, *weil* or *obwohl*?

It is somehow logical just because of `long neck and long legs`.
But here in question the reason is `long neck`

Comment: this is a biological question, not a German one... it really could be both, but most probably it is "obwohl"... although they have such a long neck, they still need to spread their legs in order to drink because their legs are still to long for their head to rech the ground...

Comment: "Weil" is "because", "obwohl" is "although" – what is it that you want to say?

Comment: Could you clarify what your question regarding the German language is? Language-wise both are correct, they just have different meanings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Please consider the `long neck and long legs`. It is somehow logical.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a question of grammar, but of meaning. The choice is the speaker's.

> Ich mag die Blumen, weil sie gelb sind.

I like flowers when they are yellow and these flowers are yellow; it follows that I like them.

> Ich mag die Blumen, obwohl sie gelb sind.

I like flowers, but not when they're yellow; these flowers are yellow, yet I like them nonetheless.

An easy way to think about this is that *obwohl* indicates the violation of some kind of expectation (for instance, expecting not to like yellow flowers).

Given your example, I assume *obwohl* was intended. If a creature has a very long neck one might expect it to be able to drink from a pond without lowering itself to the ground. However, in the case of the giraffe, that expectation is violated: they do need to get lower to the ground by spreading their legs in order to drink.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is somehow logical with points  `long neck and long legs`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **"obwohl"**. *Despite* its long neck, a giraffe must still spread its legs to reach the ground, not *because* of it (even though I found that problem quite confusing).

Answer (score 1):

"Weil" means "because (of)", "obwohl" means "despite (of)/although". So if the giraffe has to spread it's legs despite already having a long neck (implying it's long enough to drink without additional measures) then it would be "obwohl", however if the long neck is the reason for having to spread the legs and they wouldn't have to do it without that, then it makes sense to use "weil".

So the question is about semantics, not grammar. You can say both but they would imply different meanings.